# Subquery error in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT
  c.cy_id AS cy_id,
  (SELECT 
     c.to_id
   FROM c
   WHERE (c.to_id = se.ar))AS tsn,
  (SELECT
     se.x
   FROM se
   WHERE (c.to_id = se.ar)) AS X,
  (SELECT
     se.y
   FROM se
   WHERE (c.to_id = se.ar)) AS y
FROM (c
   JOIN se)
WHERE (c.to_id = se.ar)
```

This above query when i execute in mysql gives error subquery returns more than one row.
But when i do the below query it returns the result.

```
SELECT
  c.cy_id AS cy_id,
  (SELECT DISTINCT
     c.to_id
   FROM c
   WHERE (c.to_id = se.ar))AS tsn,
  (SELECT
     se.x
   FROM se
   WHERE (c.to_id = se.ar)) AS X,
  (SELECT
     se.y
   FROM se
   WHERE (c.to_id = se.ar)) AS y
FROM (c
   JOIN se)
WHERE (c.to_id = se.ar).
```

I need an reason for this.

Comment: if you use DISTINCT, the query only returns different rows, so maybe you first query returns two rows which are the same and the DISTINCT-query returns only one result because the two (or more) results are all equal. Check your first subquery and look how many rows are returned.

Comment: @Sirac: my first query doesnot return any row.it given an error saying subquery returns more than one row but when i run the second query using DISTINCT it gives me 78 rows. So what is the difference.

Comment: i meant you should run this: `SELECT 
     c.to_id
   FROM c
   WHERE (c.to_id = se.ar)` and see how many rows are returned. if there are more than one row, how have to use DISTINCT. to solve your problem without using DISTINCT you have to declare the column c.to_id as primary or unique column. (therefore check the keywords PRIMARY and UNIQUE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your c table has multiple rows, but they all have the same to_id value. If multiple records are returned by a subquery, you'll get an error.

Also, your query doesn't appear to require any subqueries. Try this and see if it gets you the results you want:

```
SELECT
  c.cy_id,
  c.to_id AS tsn,
  se.x AS X,
  se.y AS y
FROM c
   JOIN se
      ON c.to_id = se.ar
```

Comment: i have two queries which are giving me a desired result.is there any chance to combine them into one. the queries are below:
The first query is below:
SELECT
  c.cy_id,
  c.to_id AS tsn,
  se.x AS tX,
  se.y AS ty
FROM c
   JOIN se
      ON c.to_id = se.ar
union select
c.cy_id,
c.to_id AS tsn,
swt.x as tx,
swt.y as tY
from c join swt
on c.to_id = swt.ar

The second query is
SELECT
  c.cy_id,
  c.fr_id AS fsn,
  se.x AS fX,
  se.y AS fy
FROM c
   JOIN se
      ON c.fr_id = se.ar

Can i join both the queries and get the combined results with all the column names.